# Netbeans not giving hints

Tags: java, netbeans, exception, ide, hint

Normally, I get little yellow hints from Netbeans.  As can be seen, the class fails to compile, but there are no hints from Netbeans where normally I would expect to see little yellow hints on the line numbers:

[image: yellow hints on the line numbers]

**I have the throws option configured as so:**

[image: throws option configured as so]

I'm not seeing hints about declaring objects, either. It's like hints are disabled. How do I re-enable hints?

**Edit:**

```
code as follows:

package net.bounceme.dur.nntp.swing;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import net.bounceme.dur.nntp.gnu.Page;
import net.bounceme.dur.nntp.gnu.Usenet;

public class MyPanel extends JScrollPane {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyPanel.class.getName());
    private JList jList;
    private DefaultListModel defaultListModel;
    private Usenet u = Usenet.INSTANCE;
    private Page page;

    public MyPanel() {
        page = u.getPage(new Page().getPmd()); //uncaught exception
        jList = new JList(defaultListModel); // null, need to initialize
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
    }
}
```

**Stack trace showing this class failing to compile:**

```
init:
Deleting: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/build/built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/build/classes
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/src/net/bounceme/dur/nntp/swing/MyPanel.java:19: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        page = u.getPage(new Page().getPmd()); //uncaught exception
Note: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/src/net/bounceme/dur/nntp/swing/MyPanel.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/nbproject/build-impl.xml:624: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/gnumail-providers/nbproject/build-impl.xml:243: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Does hint work when you change **show as :Error** to **show as :Warning**?

Comment: that's grayed out, cannot change that.  I'm thinking it's either another setting elsewhere, or maybe the hints don't work with Swing..?

Comment: Can you post your code too so that we check , whether its problem with ur setting or ours too.

Comment: full project is on github:  https://github.com/THUFIR/gnumail-providers      it's set to checkout as a Netbeans project.  It has some JAR dependencies, however.

Comment: @Thufir have you tried re-installing NetBeans?

Comment: do you have "compile on save" checked in project properties?

Comment: I might install from the website instead through Ubuntu.  These hints work even without compile on save, which I always disable but still get hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not answer, it's additional information.  The problem resolved itself spontaneously.  Maybe it's because I quit Netbeans. Maybe it's because I rebooted.  Maybe it's gremlins:

[image]

Just to be clear, compile-on-save is still disabled and it's the same version of Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after copying an example off an internet web page. After rebooting Netbeans I did get the hints again.